# How to use multiple wildcards in Python File Dialog

Tags: python, wxpython

how can I use the code below to have the user browse for either png or jpeg files? Did I do it correctly?

```
wildcard = "pictures (*.jpeg/*.png)|*.jpeg/*.png"
dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message="Select your picture file",defaultDir=os.getcwd(),defaultFile="*.jpeg/*.png", wildcard=wildcard, style=wx.OPEN)

if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
         picfile = dlg.GetFilename()
         print picfile
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Although I am using a reference of a VB6 [website](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_add_commondialog_filters.html), the value of wildcard should be

```
wildcard = "pictures (*.jpeg,*.png)|*.jpeg;*.png"
```